# Prolog X=f(X). does not evalute true for ?-X==f(X)

Tags: prolog, logic

I know I am missing something very simple, but this bothers me a lot.
I want to test how Prolog would handle the below

```
    X=f(X).
    X=Z:- X==Y,Y==Z.
?- X==f(f(X)).
```

but obviously I am missing very basic as even ?-X=f(X). returns "false".
Could you please point out where I am wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: For me, `?- X = f(X).` on the top level succeeds, and replies `X = f(X).` Of course, unification (`=/2`) and equivalence (`==/2`) are not the same thing! You need to make it a bit clearer in your question what is your query, what is your consulted program, and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `=/2` for unification:

```
?- X = X.
true.

?- X = f(X).
X = f(X).

?- f(f(X)) = X.
X = f(f(X)).

?- X = Y, X = Z.
X = Y, Y = Z.
```

As long as you have a *free variable* on one side of the unification, it will succeed.

Equivalence, with `==/2`, is different. It only succeeds if both sides are the *same variable* or the same ground value:

```
?- X == X.
true.

?- Y == Z.
false.

?- X = Y, X = Z, Y == Z.
X = Y, Y = Z.

?- X == 3.
false.

?- X = 3, X == 3.
X = 3.
```